# Line breaks in templated HTML scriptlets

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, template-engine

If I have an HTML file test.html:

```
<p><?= str ?></p>
```

And a script function:

```
var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("test.html");
t.str = "test\nstring";
var content = t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(...).getContent();
Logger.log(content);
```

Is there any way to safely replace the newline with an HTML line break? I can use String.prototype.replace() to replace `\n` with `<br/>`, but then I'd have to use `<?!=` to disable the HTML templating engine's contextual escaping. I'm dealing with untrusted input and so I need both escaping and smart handling of line breaks. Having it contextually would be nice. As things stand, I wrote my own escaper, but it is only good for one context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two options for your scenario, the simple one is to forget the substitution entirely and use a <pre> tag, which will render your line breaks (and other formatting chars)

`<pre> <?= str ?> </pre>`

The second is to perform the substitution and sanitize your input with a custom function, so that you can safely use the force print scriptlet.

In your html:

`<?!= sanitize(str); ?>`

and in your .gs:

```
function sanitize(val){
  var vals = val.split('\n'); //split string into an array on newlines
  for(var i in vals){
    vals[i] = Encoder.htmlEncode(vals[i]);  //sanitize each element in the array
  }
  return vals.join('<br />'); //join the elements as a string, with <br /> as glue.
}
```

Note, in my example I'm using the library located here to sanitize the strings: http://www.strictly-software.com/scripts/downloads/encoder.js

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's curious, this is the code I wound up using to sanitize the untrusted input for display. It's not safe for use inside tags, in script sections, etc. That's why Google's context aware sanitization is so handy.

```
function dumbEscapeAndBreak(str) {
  return str.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
}

function _testEscape() {
  GSUnit.assertEquals('my&lt;test&lt;string&gt;is&gt;not&amp;good&amp;okay<br/>fine<br/>okay', dumbEscapeAndBreak("my<test<string>is>not&good&okay\nfine\nokay"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this:

**In your .gs script function:**

```
var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("test.html");
var paragraphs = "test\nstring";
t.str = paragraphs.split("\n");
```

**In your test.html:**

```
<?
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
?>
   <span><?= str[i]?></span><br />
   <!-- <p><?= str[i]?></p> -->
<?
}
?>
```

You can use the `<span>` or `<p>` tag, that is up to you. You can also write some simple logic to decide when to put the `<br />`, e.g. before `<span>` when `i > 0`. That will completely fulfil your `"test\nstring"`.